# GCP Spanner Import tool always creates NULL_FILTERED indexes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I noticed that the Spanner DB Export / Import tool seems to create all indexes with the NULL_FILTERED option enabled.  I have exported a database that does not have any NULL_FILTERED index options enabled.  When the database is imported, all of the indexes have the NULL_FILTERED index option enabled.  I confirmed via the log that the indexes are being created with this option enabled. I have exported the same database several times to confirm this behavior.  Only unique indexes will have the NULL_FILTERED option enabled. Anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submitting a bug on the google spanner forum, they have confirmed the issue and will work to resolve it.